# How to send email in python for values fetched from database

Tags: python, mysql, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using smtplib for values fetched from mysql database. Here, is the code:

```
db = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'Gandharv@4me', 'ashmita')
cursor = db.cursor()

sql_query = "SELECT * FROM employees1 WHERE fname = 'gandharv' "
cursor.execute(sql_query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
        firstname = row[0]
        lastname = row[1]
        role = row[2]
response = """ First Name : {}, Last Name: {}, Role : {} """.format(
        firstname, lastname, role)
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', '587')
content="FirstName: "+firstname+" Lastname: " +lastname + "Role: ",role
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('abc@gmail.com', 'myPassword')
mail.sendmail('abc@gmail.com',
                  'bcd@gmail.com', content)
mail.close()
print(response)
```

If I am using content=" knsdlkds", it works fine but if I use content =response or content="FirstName: "+firstname+" Lastname: " +lastname + "Role: ",role
It gives me TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. 
Can this be solved by casting?

Answer (score 0):

you had a typo on the content variable. can you check if this works for you.

```
HOST="localhost"
USER="root"
USER_PW="Gandharv@4me"
HOST_DB="ashmita"

gandharv = "VALUE_HERE"
sender = 'from@fromdomain.com'
debuglevel = 0

try:
    db = pymysql.connect(HOST, USER, USER_PW, HOST_DB)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM employees1 WHERE fname = '{0}' ".format(gandharv)
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    # Send Email
    firstname = result[0]
    lastname = result[1]
    role = result[2]
    receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

    response = " First Name : {0}, Last Name: {1}, Role : {2} ".format(firstname, lastname, role)

    try:
        smtp = SMTP()
        smtp.set_debuglevel(debuglevel)
        smtp.connect('YOUR.MAIL.SERVER', 26)
        smtp.login('USERNAME@DOMAIN', 'PASSWORD')
        smtp.sendmail(sender, receivers, response)
        smtp.quit()
        print(response)

    except SMTPException:
        print "Error: unable to send email"

except Exception as e:
    print "Error: {0}".format(e)
```

Comment: btw why you are using a loop to parse 3 fields? you can use fetchone

Comment: Well, the code works fine and I am able to see the values but the email part doesn't work.

Comment: ok, I will modify the code to make it work; but you need to change the credentials. hold on...